# How to change mysql statement depending on how many variables with php

Tags: php, mysql

So basically I have website that has names of cities that can be checked off. I save them into  local storage under one key. And then I send them Via Ajax over to my php script below. Then in php I explode the city variable on "," and I filter the cities depending on which ones were given. But right now I only know how to do this manually, for example city[0], city[1] etc. Is there a way I can continually put those variables into mysql statement depending on how many there are? I am sorry if I am being confusing, I'm just totally lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die('could not connect to mysql');

mysql_select_db("test", $con) or die('could not find database');


$city2 = $_POST['city2'];

$cities = explode(",", $city2);

$rep2 = $_POST['rep2'];

$status2 = $_POST['status2'];

$size2 = $_POST['size2'];

$type2 = $_POST['type2'];

$lat2 = $_POST['lat2'];

$long2 = $_POST['long2'];

$radius2 = $_POST['radius2'];

if ($city2 == '') {
    $city_stat = " city RLIKE '.*' ";
} else {
    $city_stat = " (city='$cities[0]' OR city='$cities[1]') ";

}


if ($radius2 == '') {
    $radius_stat = '10';
} else {
    $radius_stat = $_POST['radius2'];

}


if ($size2 == '') {
    $size_stat = '';
} else {
    $size_stat = " AND size='$size2' ";

}

if ($rep2 == '') {
    $rep_stat = '';
} else {
    $rep_stat = " AND rep='$rep2' ";

}


if ($status2 == '') {
    $status_stat = '';
} else {
    $status_stat = " AND status='$status2' ";

}



$result = mysql_query("SELECT lat,lng,id,rep,rep_num,name,city,state,zip,address,status,category,size FROM test WHERE $city_stat $rep_stat $size_stat $status_stat LIMIT 0 , 50 ");

while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array_json[] = $array;




}


echo json_encode($array_json);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I think you are asking is that there might be a variable number of cities and you want to set a conditional that the city can be any of them.

So instead of:

```
$city_stat = " (city='$cities[0]' OR city='$cities[1]') ";
```

You can do something like this:

```
$city_stat = '(city IN ('.implode(',',$cities).'))';
```

Comment: when i try this, it returns no results, this was mysql query that ran  SELECT lat,lng,id,rep,rep_num,name,city,state,zip,address,status,category,size FROM hospitals WHERE (city IN (Abington))    LIMIT 0 , 50 null

Comment: This is because the city name is a string but does not have quotes around it.  To get around this we need to make sure each city in the cities array has quotes around the name.  We can do something like this with:

$city_list = implode(',',$cities);
$city_string = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $cities) . "'";

$city_stat = '(city IN ('.$city_string.'))';

Comment: okay so i tried that and this is what my sql query came out as SELECT lat,lng,id,rep,rep_num,name,city,state,zip,address,status,category,size FROM hospitals WHERE (city IN ('Array'))    LIMIT 0 , 50 null

Comment: Oops, replace $city_string = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $cities) . "'";

with

$city_string = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $city_list) . "'";